# Sort arrays of protocols in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview

I have a lot of arrays stored in a ViewController of the following:

```
protocol AlarmClockType {
    var alarmLabel: String { get set }
    var sound: AlarmSound { get set }
    var snooze: Bool { get set }
    var alarmType: AlarmType { get set }
    var alarmOn: Bool { get set }
    var alarm: NSTimer? { get set }
    var attributedTitle: NSMutableAttributedString { get }

    static var DocumentsDirectory: NSURL { get }
    static var ArchiveURL: NSURL { get }

    func timeToAlarm(prayerTimes: [String: String]?) -> NSDate
    }
}
```

Each instance has a property alarmTime (which is NSDate). How can I sort the array based on time?

To make it more clear:

It's a TableViewController and the cells display alarm times. Each time the user adds an alarm, the tableView should be sorted by alarm times.

Comment: Using the array .sort function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to sort an array by dates, it's probably better if you use a custom data structure that includes an NSDate.

For example, you can create a struct that has properties for your data.

```
struct Alarm {
    var alarmTime: NSDate = NSDate()
    var description: String = ""
}
```

This struct can be used to create an array.

```
let alarms = [
    Alarm(alarmTime: NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(120),
          description: "alarm 60 s in the future"), 
    Alarm(alarmTime: NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(30),
           description: "alarm 30 s in the future"), 
    Alarm(alarmTime: NSDate().dateByAddingTimeInterval(90),
          description: "alarm 90 s in the future")
]
```

The array can be sorted using the sort function and some special syntax for handling NSDates.

```
let sortedAlarms = alarms.sort(
    { $0.alarmTime.compare($1.alarmTime) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedAscending }
)
```

Finally, in this example, `sortedAlarms` contains everything in `alarms` but it is sorted by the NSDate in `alarmTime`.

---

The data in the array can be easily accessed. For example, to get the alarm time from the first alarm in the sorted alarms array, use the following code.

```
let alarmTime = sortedAlarms[0].alarmTime
```

After the alarms are sorted, you will want to reload the data in your table view using `tableView.reloadData()`.

Comment: Thank you this really helped! :)